# Installation of prodigal

Tags: command-line, permissions

I am trying to install prodigal.

I downloaded it and extracted it in a particular location and in terminal I when I used the command:

```
make Install
```

After reaching that location it showed error:

```
install -d -m 0755 /usr/local/bin
install -m 0755 prodigal /usr/local/bin
install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/prodigal': Permission denied
Makefile:43: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I also tried to change the `INSTALLDIR` in the make file and then wrote `make install`. It made a directory(from home to prodigal) in the prodigal folder itself and again error came like

```
install -d -m 0755 /usr/local/bin
install -m 0755 prodigal /usr/local/bin
```

Do I need to change something else in make file?

Comment: Thank you so much for promoting. Prodigal is installed now RGI is working fine now in my system

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to install the program in a system owned folder you should use `sudo` in order to run the command as `root`.

```
sudo make install
```

or (depending on the correct spelling of the install command)

```
sudo make Install
```

Note: it might be possible to install the program without using `sudo` in your home directory. However - this option will require more changes in the `Makefile` to set all relevant paths to point to your home-directory.

Comment: We should also recommend [CheckInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) I think, especially to new users.

Comment: I have used this but again same problem came

Comment: @chhaya - what happened when you first execute `sudo bash` and then follows by running the command `make install`?

Comment: the file format which i was giving ti RGI was in pieces of fasta not a complete string of fasta. that is why it was not taking it. i googlled the error and many said that may be prodigal is not installed properly. its my stupidity that i dint check whether iit is installed or not. it had already installed it with brew command and thought that is not working and tried to do it again. i am completely new to this field and you all may feel unprofessional. the format of fasta file was not proper. all this has nothing to do with prodigal installation. Thank you so much